# Webview Doesn't shows the images in android 4.0?

Tags: android, webview, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

Recently I was working on an app for Android 2.2 . I am using the same app on android 4.0 But, the webview doesn't displays the images and just shows a white screen.

I have just used simple code:

```
WebView mWebView2 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webViewQ2);
mWebView2.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
mWebView2.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebView1.loadDataWithBaseURL("","<table width=\"100%\"><tr><td style=\"text-align:center; background-color:#c8c8c8;\">Question</td></tr></table>"+answer1, "text/html", "utf-8", "");
mWebView2.loadDataWithBaseURL("","<table width=\"100%\"><tr><td style=\"text-align:center; background-color:#c8c8c8;\">Question</td></tr></table>"+answer2, "text/html", "utf-8", "");
```

Anyone could help me Please all my code is working fine but this point.

Note:It sometimes automatically shows the images and sometimes doesnt show any thing.

Comment: Have you tried giving it properly formatted HTML? That is, add `<html>` and `<body>` tags.

Comment: I think if the Html was working good on Android 2.2 then it must be ok to run

Comment: answer1 contains this  <img src ="+"\"file:////data/data//com.cuelearn.main/temp/temptest/"+Arrays[i]+"\"> 

This points the file i am reffering to..

Answer (score 1):

```
String htmlContent="<body style="+"text-align:center;"+"><img  src=\""+url+"\"/></body>";
mywebview.loadDataWithBaseURL("not_needed", htmlContent, "text/html", "utf-8", "not_needed");
```

Use this in your code. It is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you're certain that your HTML isn't malformed, you can try disabling hardware acceleration on the WebView.

[As explained here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html), try the following:

```
WebView mWebView2 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webViewQ2);
myWebView2.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

Comment: What API level are you targeting?